# Stack Sigma comparing dates

Tags: sql, stripe-payments

I'm trying to compare dates on Stripe Sigma and have a query that looks like this

```
subscriptions.created < '2020-02-14'
```

But I get an error that I'm not used to with SQl

```
FAILED: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 10:26: '<' cannot be applied to timestamp, varchar(10)
```

How would I compare dates, here?

Comment: I am not aware of this tool. But from documentation try `subscriptions.created  < (timestamp '2020-02-14 00:00:00 +0000')`

Comment: Or `date'2020-02-14'`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see how it goes:

```
subscriptions.created < date('2020-02-14')
```